# Need to store html tag in json file

Tags: javascript, json, protractor

I am working on protractor test case which loads the test data from a json file. the json data consist of a div and its css properties. I did this so that i move all my hard coded values to a different file so that my code looks good.
Here is my JSON file

```
 {"road_button":"div[ng-click=\"setLocation(\'report_road\')\"]",        "road_missing":"div[ ng-click=\"mapFeedBack.editObject= mapFeedBack.createMapObjectModel();setLocation(mapFeedBack.noMap?\'road_new\':\'choose_location_road_new/road_new\')"]",}
```

When i try to include the file in my spec.js it shows error **Unexpected token '**
I want to use the css property for my click functionality

```
var data=require('./mapfeedback_testdata.json');    
element.all(by.css(data.road_button)).click();
```

I would really appreciate your comments and news ways in which i can deal with this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really bad practice to put your selectors in a JSON file and call them after. You're supposed to put them directly inside your test files as you can see in [the official style guide](http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide).

If you want to respect the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and need to use the same selectors multiple times, just declare them as variables or constants.